# Ошибка ORA-00904

Tags: oracle, sql

Добрый день!

Есть запрос:

```
select td.*, 
       r.name result_name, 
       e.name_f||' '||e.name_i||' '||e.name_o employeer_name, 
       tm.comments mail_comments,
       tm.delivered mail_delivered,
       tm.receive_date receive_date, 
       tm.num mail_num 
from   todo_items td 
left   join results r 
on     td.result_id=r.id 
left   join employeers e 
on     td.employeer_id=e.id 
left   join todo_mails tm 
on     tm.todo_item_id=td.id 
where  1=1 
and    td.project_id=1037 
and    result_id=0  

union all

select td.*, 
       r.name result_name, 
       e.name_f||' '||e.name_i||' '||e.name_o employeer_name, 
       tm.comments mail_comments,
       tm.delivered mail_delivered,
       tm.receive_date receive_date, 
       tm.num mail_num 
from   input_form_logs td 
left   join results r 
on     td.result_id=r.id 
left   join employeers e 
on     td.employeer_id=e.id 
left   join todo_mails tm 
on     tm.todo_item_id=td.id 
where  1=1 
and    td.project_id=1037 
and    result_id=0 

order  by td.item_date, 
       td.order_num;
```

При выполнении данного запроса выдает ошибку:

```
ORA-00904: "TD"."ORDER_NUM": недопустимый идентификатор
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 29 Column: 24
```

Т.е. если убрать `order by td.item_date, td.order_num`, то всё работает. Уточните, пожалуйста, как правильно применить `order by`  к данному SQL запросу.

Спасибо!

Comment: @DVirt, а в таблице `input_form_logs` точно есть поле `ORDER_NUM`?

Comment: Если так написать, будет работать?

order by item_date, order_num;

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант обернуть в ещё один запрос.

```
select * from (...) t order by t.item_date, t.order_num;
```

Answer (score 2):

Основная проблема в том что `ORDER BY` выполняется после `UNION ALL` и `SELECT`. Соответственно `ORDER` не видит данных из таблицы `todo_items td`, а только результаты выполнения `SELECT`. Для проведения сортировки необходимо убрать алиасы таблицы из`ORDER`:

```
select td.*, 
       r.name result_name, 
       e.name_f||' '||e.name_i||' '||e.name_o employeer_name, 
       tm.comments mail_comments,
       tm.delivered mail_delivered,
       tm.receive_date receive_date, 
       tm.num mail_num 
from   todo_items td 
left   join results r 
on     td.result_id=r.id 
left   join employeers e 
on     td.employeer_id=e.id 
left   join todo_mails tm 
on     tm.todo_item_id=td.id 
where  1=1 
and    td.project_id=1037 
and    result_id=0    
union all    
select td.*, 
       r.name result_name, 
       e.name_f||' '||e.name_i||' '||e.name_o employeer_name, 
       tm.comments mail_comments,
       tm.delivered mail_delivered,
       tm.receive_date receive_date, 
       tm.num mail_num 
from   input_form_logs td 
left   join results r 
on     td.result_id=r.id
left   join employeers e 
on     td.employeer_id=e.id 
left   join todo_mails tm 
on     tm.todo_item_id=td.id 
where  1=1 
and    td.project_id=1037 
and    result_id=0    
order  by item_date, 
       order_num;
```

Answer (score 1):

order by 1,2 - где 1 и 2 это порядковые номера столбцов

Comment: Не поможет т.к. есть конструкция UNION ALL не поддерживающая сортировку :) нужно делать обертываение конструкции и поверх делать сортировку.